# How to prevent my app from stopping media player when I come to home

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

So I'm developing an app which uses android MediaPlayer in it. It plays the audio from an url. Now I want my app to continue playing the audio even if I come to home or press exit. The audio is only playing when I'm inside the app. Thanks in advance

Comment: What device are you testing this on?

Comment: On my personal phone running Android 10 model: VIVO V 11 Pro

Comment: Did you read [dontkillmyapp for VIVO](https://dontkillmyapp.com/vivo)?

Comment: Yes I did. Also I tested it on the emulator too. But nothing helped me. Shall I share my code?